# How to randomly select 10 items from csv dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, case

In my .csv file I have 12 countries in total (with 12 capitals) I want to randomly select 10 of those 12 countries however.

I've found from stackoverflow resources some single or pair selection but not randomly select 10 items from a dictionary. How can I do this?

This is the relevant code I have for a countries and capitals exam where user inputs the capital to the country asked, and outputs a correct or incorrect answer.

```
    #Defining the function of reading .csv file from path into dictionary
def readCsvIntoDictionary(path):
    dic = {}
    with open(path, 'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            dic[row[0]] = row[1];
    return dic;

count = 0;

    # for loop with key variable definition in dic
for key in dic:
    # ans variable defined for user input
    ans = input('What is the capital of ' + key + '?\n')
    # User can input lower and upper answers
    if(ans.lower() == dic[key].lower()):
        # key lookup in dic (dictionary) if answer is correct at end of the loop
        dic[key] = 'Correct! ' + dic[key] + ' is the capital of ' + key;
        count = count + 1;
    else:
        # key lookup in dic (dictionary) if answer is incorrect at end of the loop
        dic[key] = 'Wrong! \'' + ans + '\' is not the capital of ' + key + ', it\'s ' + dic[key];
```

Thanks!

Comment: [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) might work for you. `random.sample(list(dic), 10)` gives you 10 random keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) the keys:

```
for key in random.sample(dic.keys(), 10):
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the right solution. I just adjusted the 'for key in ...'

Comment: However I have an issue. When I run the program, 2 of the capitals still appear (the ones that aren't randomly selected) on the output.

Comment: @BudDoward Nothing in the code you've provided would do that. That issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: For example, it will go "London, Paris, and 10 correct or incorrect answers" when London and Paris aren't permitted in the random capitals. And then if I run it again it will randomise to another 2 capitals, since there are a total of 12 capitals from the dictionary. 
The issue must lie in the fcorrect/wrong line of my code.

Comment: @BudDoward I think this is happening in code that isn't provided here. I'd recommend asking a new question with the relevant section of code if you're not able to track it down yourself.